# Not able to move DIV around

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following code:

```
<textarea>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#996633" onMouseover=javascript:ShowContent("menu7_items") onMouseout=javascript:HideContent("menu7_items")>
 <p>&nbsp;Stock Update&nbsp;</p>
 <div id="menu7_items" style="display:none;" onMouseover=javascript:ShowContent("menu7_items") onMouseout=javascript:HideContent("menu7_items")>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <td align="left"><a href="/materials/SearchPaper.do">Update Paper</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</td>
</textarea>
```

There is a TD inside which there is a DIV and inside DIV there is a Table. DIV's default style is display:none. On mouseover TD, the div should appear like a popup in a given position. But it is not happening. DIV is appearing in the same TD. How to make DIV's position independent of TD.

Answer (score 3):

`position: absolute;`

You may also want to specify the direction properties (top, right, bottom, left), but try it without those first to see how it looks. If you use them, you may want to use position: relative on the parent to position the absolute child relative to it (the same works with any position value that isn't "static", the default).

Comment: If he solved your problem, click the "accept answer" checkbox to the left.